# Rewriting pixel data in a DICOM file results in a non-DICOM file

Tags: export

**Goal**: Given a CT image series, to apply a gaussian blur filter to every CT 
slice.

My code looks like this:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

(* Every CT slice is a .dcm file *)
dcmFiles = FileNames["~/Desktop/mydcm-orig/*.dcm"];

(* Import data into a list of rules *)
importDCM[file_] := Import[file, "Rules"];
getRules[k_] := importDCM[dcmFiles[[k]]]

(* Extract intensity values from the list of rules *)
getData[k_] := ("Data" /. getRules[k])[[1]]

(* Apply a Gaussian Blur filter at kth-image with a radius `r' *)
doGF[k_, r_] := GaussianFilter[getData[k], r]

(* Replace old data with new in the list of rules *)   
newRules[k_] :=
   getRules[k] /. HoldPattern["Data" -> _] :> ("Data" -> doGF[k, 1])

(* Create a .dcm file from the list of rules *)
rewriteDCM[k_] := 
 Export["~/Desktop/mydcm-blur/" <> ToString@k <> ".dcm", newRules[k]]

(* Do it for all files *)
Table[rewriteDCM@k, {k, 1, Length@dcmFiles}];
```

When I try to open the new file with a DICOM viewer I get an error that this is not a valid DICOM file. Also the new file is a few bytes long instead of ~0.5MB. Apparently the `Data` rule is empty, i.e. `Data -> {}`.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

A sample anonymized dicom file [may be found in this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nx2hcaugoloykwq/sample.dcm?dl=0).

---

The following MATLAB code works for me, but I'd like to make it work with Mathematica!

```
clear all
clc

target = uigetdir('Select DICOM folder to blur');
cd(target);

% Get an array with the filenames in the `target' dir
strFiles = dir(target);
files = strvcat({strFiles.name});

[nFiles, y] = size(files);
for i = 3:nFiles    % skip . and ..
    currentFile = files(i,:);
    fprintf('Blurring %s\n', currentFile);

    [d1, map] = dicomread(currentFile);
    % Apply gaussian filter to pixel data with sigma = 0.5
    newData = imgaussfilt(d1,0.5);
    metadata = dicominfo(currentFile);
    outputDir = 'C:\\Users\\stathis\\Desktop\\blurred\\';
    dicomwrite(newData, ...
        sprintf('%s%s.dcm', outputDir, currentFile), ...
        metadata, 'CreateMode', 'copy');    
end
```

Left: original image, Right: blurred

[image]

Comment: Part of your problem is that you need to use `Export[file, rules, "Rules"]`, since you imported it as such. On the other hand, when I try that I keep getting an `"Invalid DICOM format"` error.

Comment: Thanks for caring @b3m2a1. Not even Export[file, Import[file, rules], "Rules"] work. So it must be some deficiency in Mathematica :(

Comment: yeah it calls the data invalid so the exporter is clearly misimplemented. File a report with WRI and they should fix in.

Comment: Ok, I filled a bug report and I'll keep you posted. Thanks again!